# Regarding awk, I need first column as is and next columns to be changed

Tags: bash, awk

I have a input file as below

```
a x g
b y h
c z i
```

output required :

```
a ["x "] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```

Tried below code but each column is displaying in next line, please help in getting the desired output

```
awk '{print $1;for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf "[\""$i"\"]"" ";print "" }'
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you decide between `["x "]` and `["y"]`? When should the space be added and when not?

Comment: you understand how `printf` works inside your loop, right? you need a `printf` to start the line too. Good luck.

Comment: Btw. with GNU sed: `sed 's/[^ ]/["&"]/2g' file`

Comment: `print` adds a newline character. Use `printf` to have explicit control over where the newline should occur.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the first `x` has a trailing space, but if that was a typo, here is a simple solution which modifies each field but the first one in every line:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) $i="[\""$i"\"]";print}' <<EOF
a x g
b y h
c z i
EOF
a ["x"] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```

or with [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-sprintf_0028_0029-function-1):

```
{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) $i=sprintf("[\"%s\"]", $i);print}
```

Both programs can be rewritten to `{for...}1`, dropping the final `print` and replacing it with a separate `1` rule.

Answer (score 1):

Making a couple small changes to OP's current code:

```
$ awk '{printf $1;for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) printf " [\""$i"\"]";print "" }' test.dat
             ^             ^                        ^
a ["x"] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```

Applying a couple varitions on the `printf` calls:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s",$1;for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) printf " [\"%s\"]",$i;print "" }' test.dat
a ["x"] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`. I assume that your file always has three columns.

```
while read c1 c2 c3; do echo "$c1 [\"$c2\"] [\"$c3\"]"; done
```

or

```
q='"';
while read c1 c2 c3; do echo "$c1 [$q$c2$q] [$q$c3$q]"; done <file
```

<file
Output:

```
a ["x"] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk  '{for(i=NF; i>1; i--) $i="[\""$i"\"]"}1' input 
a ["x"] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```

Answer (score 0):

skip the looping :

```
echo '
a x g
b y h
c z i' |
```

---

```
mawk 'gsub(/ +[^ ]+/, "&\"]", $!(NF = NF))_' OFS=' ["'
```

---

```
a ["x"] ["g"]
b ["y"] ["h"]
c ["z"] ["i"]
```